# Windows 10 touchscreen touch only upper left corner after upgrade to 1703

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

My old Asus i5 x64 tablet was working fine with windows 10 for a while. Yesterday however it got the 1703 upgrade which has broken the touchscreen functionality.

This tablet comes with an additional wacom pen which works fine, however when I touch the screen, I see that only the upper left corner gets triggered. Regardless of where I touch, it is always upper left.

This tablet is old, there is no hardware drivers that I can update and since windows force installs updates automatically it has basically made my tablet useless.

Things I've tried:

- Recalibrating the display
- Disabling/Re-Enabling HID touchscreen
- Removing/Re-adding HID touchscreen
- Searched for more updates on the hardware
- Disabling snapping (was disabled)

Edit: So user Ramhound suggested to revert to previous edition, that fixed the issue but since you cannot defer updates indefinitely, the problem will resurface later.

Comment: If you revert back to 1607 do these functions return?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll revert and check. This might take several hours, however

Comment: It is really the only way to rule out software vs hardware at this point.  The pen working on only a certain part of your screen indicates a possible hardware problem.

Comment: @Ramhound rolling back fixed, thanks for the hint. How can I pin this version to avoid getting 1703 at the next update cycle?

Comment: You can only defer a feature update for 6 months, and thats only if you have Windows 10 Professional/Enterprise/Education.  Windows Home is always stuck on Current Branch.   If the device is new enough its possible ASUS will resolve the problem with a new driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is finally here!

We got the same issue on a lot of monitors at work (Mikka with 3M touch), the exact same issue infact. No calibration, driver update, reinstall whatever will solve the problem - it will only activate the upper left corner no matter where you touch.

It is solved with Windows 10 1709!